# What is the branch of mathematics that relates to equations of sums of sets of integers?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, summation

Suppose I have 10 unique digits in a possible sequence from 0-9.

```
0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I arrange them in a table like this:

```
   4
  35
 987
1026
```

In this arrangement I have used every possible integer, and the bottom row is the sum of the first three rows.

ie `4 + 35 + 987 = 1026`

Now I know this is not the only answer to this problem. Brute-forcing it gives me about `228` valid solutions.

But I think there must be a way to encode the relationships between the numbers so I can work out precisely how many possible solutions there are.

To do that I need to know the branch of mathematics this relates to.

My question is: **What is the branch of mathematics that relates to equations of sums of sets of integers?**

Comment: [Cryptarithmetic problem](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/cryptarithmetic-problem/)?